# How to use DTO in swagger examples

Tags: javascript, nestjs, swagger, swagger-ui

I am building an update API in nest js and I want to document my API. In this update API I have different types of users and based on those users I have different properties (some properties are common across all type of users).

I want to use those DTOs as an example for those different users. How can I do that?

I have tried this code:

```
export const updateDirectoryExample = Object.freeze({
  sample_1: {
    summary: 'Contractor',
    value: { ...new UpdateDirectoryContractorDto() },
  },
});
```

Controller code:

```
@ApiOkResponse({
    type: UpdateDirectoryResDto,
  })
  @ApiBody({
    type: UpdateDirectoryDto,
    examples: updateDirectoryExample,
  })
  updateDirectory(
    @AuthUser() reqUserDetails: IRequestUserDetails,
    @Body() body: UpdateDirectoryDto,
    @Req() request: Request,
  ) {
    return this.directoryService.updateDirectory(reqUserDetails, body, request);
  }
```

This code shows an empty object in the UI instead of those properties defined in the DTO.

Answer (score 2):

If your `UpdateDirectoryContractorDto` is a normal NestJS DTO with a bunch of decorated fields but no constructor, then calling `new UpdateDirectoryContractorDto()` is going to return a blank DTO instance where all the fields are undefined.

This means that the value of `{ ...new UpdateDirectoryContractorDto() }` when rendered to JSON by Swagger is just going to be an empty object. Instead, you should pass the exact object you are expecting to see as the value for `examples`.

```
export const updateDirectoryExample = Object.freeze({
  sample_1: {
    summary: 'Contractor',
    value: { 
      field1: "value1",
      field2: "value2",
    },
  },
});
```